# How can I write a numpy.array to a file and retain all of the digits?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, repr

Suppose I have a numpy array with some high precision floats obtained from `scipy.optimize.minimize`, such as: `arr = np.array([9.2387213981273981, 0.3219837123801298])`. I would like to write this array with this level of precision to a file in a way like the following:

```
filename = 'parameters.py'
f = open(filename, 'w')
f.write('from numpy import *' + '\n')
f.write('arr = ' + repr(arr))
f.close()
```

However, this doesn't work, since `repr(arr)` returns `'array([9.2387214 , 0.32198371])'`, and there is a high level of precision loss here. One potential way to fix this is to convert `arr` to a list and write the list to the file instead:

```
L = list(arr)
filename = 'parameters.py'
f = open(filename, 'w')
f.write('L = ' + repr(L))
f.close()
```

Here, `repr(L)` returns `'[9.238721398127398, 0.3219837123801298]'`, and so there is no precision loss. My question is, how can I write the array to a file without converting it to a list, so that the there is no precision loss?

Comment: Text isn't a good format for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.printoptions`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.printoptions.html#numpy.printoptions) context manager and set the `precision` to, say, 15:

```
with np.printoptions(precision=15), open(filename, "w") as fh:
    fh.write("from numpy import *\n")
    fh.write("arr = " + repr(arr))
```

after which the file looks like:

```
from numpy import *
arr = array([9.238721398127398, 0.32198371238013 ])
```

Comment: (also noting the [`np.save`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) and [`np.load`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.load.html#numpy.load) functions.)